# Gradle project error - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot

This is my main application code:

```
package u.d.dip.rs.app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;

@EnableWebSecurity
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "u.d.dip")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class DipApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DipApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I'm using gradle to build the project. Even though SpringApplication file is properly imported I'm getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm getting following gradle message when I hover over SpringApplication

```
[Gradle: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.5.1.RELEASE] org.springframework.boot public class SpringApplication extends Object
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure if its a typo only here but your class name is `DigApplication` - Di*g* with a *g* and you try to run `DipApplication` - Di*p* with a *p*. Also, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` is not needed when you use `@SpringBootApplication` as it already contains it.

Comment: Do a gradle clean build and you should run application

Comment: @Tom  Thanks for pointing out the typo. I've edited the question. But that's not what is causing the error.

Comment: How do you run your application? How is gradle relevant?

Comment: @JBNizet Gradle is important because I'm resolving all my dependencies through that. Since the kind of error that I'm getting is because of spring-boot related issue, which is available as an external library in my project.

Comment: OK. So you **build** your app with Gradle. That doesn't tell us how you **run** your application, and how gradle is relevant here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was because of an issue with gradle 3.4 I've changed my gradle distribution to 3.2 and everything is working fine now.

Please refer this for more information:
https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1335

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using IntelliJ Idea, the new version 2016.3.6 solved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I fix this error by change gradle3.4 to 3.2

Answer (score 1):

i encountered this problem too, just with another story.

i am using spring boot 2.2.5 and gradle 5.1.2.

run `gradle build -x test`, it will tell you what error it is.

in my case, it told me that `error: package org.jasig.cas.client.authentication does not exist`, but this package exists in fact.

then i remembered that i added a dependency `runtimeOnly 'org.apereo.cas:cas-server-support-validation:5.3.15.1'`

after comment this dependency, my project can start success.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is an old thread, but still adding an answer.

Spring Boot will add two jars under build\libs\ (once we execute ./gradlew clean build or equivalent) *.jar(this will be jar with all dependencies) and *-plain.jar(will not have any dependencies). Now *-plain.jar is getting picked up and executed and causing No manifest and Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication (once we fix no manifest by providing manifest under jar {}).

We need to run *.jar using java -jar command. If we want to stop generating *-plain.jar , we have to simply add following in our build.gradle :

```
jar {
enabled = false
}
```