# Gradle spring-boot error - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea, gradle-plugin

Below is my build.gradle file. I am using java 11 and IntelliJ 2019.2.2. As I run the application, I get: *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication*

As such the error or problem appears to be the same as the one you get when you upgrade from gradle version 2.x to anything 3.4 onwards, but I should not be getting the error with any recent IntelliJ version. I have cleaned the repository, idea cache etc. The main class (com.itreatmd.emr.Application) has only one line  - *SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args)* and that throws this exception.

Also, when I build the tar file from command line and then explode the tar file, I do not see my jar file packaged under the lib folder of the tar file. I am clearly missing something, presumably something obvious, but just cannot get the handle to it.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.2.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}"
    }
}


plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.1.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'idea'
}
mainClassName = 'com.itreatmd.emr.Application'
group = 'com.itreatmd.emr'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    baseName = 'emrServices'
    version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey'
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.7'
    compile group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.5'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20180813'
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.3"
    compile group: 'org.yaml', name: 'snakeyaml', version: '1.8'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.3.1'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: '3.1.1.RELEASE'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.itreatmd.emr.Application',
                'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.files.collect { "lib/$it.name" }.join(' ')
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle project error - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42628920/gradle-project-error-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-boo)

Comment: No, I am afraid it didn't. The problem discussed in that question was related to IntelliJ versions of of 2016. My symptoms are identical neverthless.

Answer (score 0):

i am using spring boot 2.2.5 and gradle 5.1.2.

run `gradle build -x test`, it will tell you what error it is.

in my case, it told me that `error: package org.jasig.cas.client.authentication does not exist`, but this package exists in fact.

then i remembered that i added a dependency `runtimeOnly 'org.apereo.cas:cas-server-support-validation:5.3.15.1'`

after comment this dependency, my project can start success.